# how to clear cookies , cache , and browsing history in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

how to clear cookies , cache , and browsing history in as3

Comment: You mean ALL cookies, cache and browsing history?

Comment: In what context? As a Flash file in a web page (or in web content in general) you have no access to the the user's global history/cache/cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot clear the browser's cookies, cache or history from within Flash. Flash runs in its own sandbox that does not have access to these things. In fact you can't even do it with Javascript as far as I know.